# Java - Retorno de um método double limitado a 2 casas decimais

Tags: java, return, double

Olá!

Quero fazer um método do tipo double com retorno limitado a duas casas decimais.

Vou aplicar em um método de uma classe que contem uma lista.
Esse método retorna média dos números nos elementos da lista

```
...já há um código acima com elementos em uma lista

public double media(){
   double soma = ***percorrer a lista e somar os elementos***
   int quant = ***quantidade de elementos somados no vetor

   double media = soma / quant;

   return media;
}
```

Eu não sei qual será o resultado da média, mas quero que o retorno limite em 2 casas decimais.

Exemplo:

media = 3.3333333     retorno = 3.33

media = 7.5829     retorno = 7.58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a Classe DecimalFormat do Java, ficaria dessa forma:

```
public double formatar(double media){

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
return decimalFormat.format(media);
```

}

[Veja a doc aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

[Aqui um artigo sobre o tema](https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/java/java-arredondar-ou-truncar-double-com-2-casas-decimais#:%7E:text=Truncar%20valor%20Double%20em%20Java&text=Os%20dois%20fazem%20uso%20da,arredondamento%20para%20o%20tipo%20RoundingMode.)